# Create physical existence folder in Custom project Template of xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am new developer to use XCode I trying to Create custom project template and any how I success but I create folder using Groups key in .plist file. Folder which are created after selecting my custom project template have no physical existence. I want to create folder which have physical existence please help me out from this problem.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In .plist file add these lines. It will create folder and group of AppDelegate class.

```
<key>Classes/AppDelegate/AppDelegate.h</key>
<dict>
<key>Group</key>
<array>
<string>Classes</string>
<string>AppDelegate</string>
</array>
<key>Path</key>
<string>Classes/AppDelegate.h</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it by below line of code.

```
<key>Classes/AppDelegate/AppDelegate.h</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Group</key>
        <array>
            <string>Classes</string>
            <string>AppDelegate</string>
        </array>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Classes/AppDelegate.h</string>
    </dict>
```

Add this line of code in your template .plist file it will create folder as well as group of AppDelegate class

Comment: Should be <key>Path</key>
        <string>Classes/AppDelegate/AppDelegate.h</string> ?

Comment: @AnshulKhandelwal i am also using above code for my Appdelegate.swift file but its not working for me do you have any idea.