# Create "physical" folder for Xcode custom template

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode-template

Want to create my custom template for Xcode. Idea - to create simple template with predefined structure of folders.

I found [this](https://github.com/acani/custom-xcode-templates) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20755267/2012219) resourses

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018361/2012219) approach only create groups but not folders.

For example i want to create something like this

[image]

for this prepare

[image]

This create for me netx logical structure in xCode

[image]

But physically in folder i still haven't any folders:

[image]

What i want to achive -

[image]

Question - is it possible to create physical folder with template for xCode?
Also how to move `Assets.xcassets` folder in subfolders? (when move with group xCode "think" that this is file and promt about this).

Comment: It's spelled "Xcode", not "xCode"

Comment: Have you tried setting the structure up with `groups` then using https://github.com/venmo/synx ?

Comment: @Ríomhaire interesting solution, but also want to found answer for my uestions, anyway i;ll try it, thanks

Comment: Cool - let us know if it works. :)

Comment: @gbk did you found any solution for creation of physical  folder.